# Create a trigger dealing with two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables. Table A is like

```
Name   color
a1      red
a2      yellow
a3      black
a4      blue
```

Table B is like

```
Name    minutes    action
b1      10          jump
b2      20          run
b3      40          dance
```

I am creating a trigger to insert row in table B. If the action is existed in B. Then I print the new added info. Also, if the new added persons's color is red, I will count how many people having more/less minutes in table B. The code is like

```
create or replace trigger TR_insert_count
Before INSERT On B
For each row 

DECLARE
l_act integer;
l_less integer;
l_more integer;
l_equal integer;

Begin 

select count(1) into l_act
From B
Where Action=:new.Action;

select count(*)
into l_less
From B
Where Action=:new.Action and MINUTES > :new.minutes;

select count(*)
into l_more
From B
Where Action=:new.Action and MINUTES < :new.minutes;

select count(*)
into l_equal
From B
Where Action=:new.Action and MINUTES = :new.minutes;

if(l_act>0) then
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('There is duplicate.');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('The new input info is with name ' || :new.Name || ' with 
activity ' || :new.action ||' for ' ||:new.minutes || ' minutes.'); 

   if(:new.name in (select Name From A where color='red')) then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('There are '||l_more ||'people having more minutes.');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('There are '||l_less ||'people having less minutes.');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('There are '||l_equal ||'people having the same minutes.');
   end if;

end if;
end
```

It is compiled , but when inserted row, it report error saying trigger invalid. I wonder is it because of the row-level or table-level trigger I have here, what to do please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check warnings after compiling your trigger, it will give you exact reason why it can't be compiled.

However, when you fix compilation error[s], you will hit 
"ORA-04091: table XXXX is mutating... " during inserting into `B` :  You cannot issue query against target table inside row level trigger unless it uses autonomous transactions.

The common workaround involves creating 3 triggers, 2 statement levels - BEFORE and AFTER action, and one row level (there are quite a few articles that describe this approach , for instance https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551198119097816936 ) .

Comment: Thanks, fixed, but still think about how to solve it, maybe separate it into 2 triggers.

Comment: 2 triggers won't help - you will need to use 3 as described in the article. Another option is to create stored procedure that inserts data into `B` and prints required information. Then you can revoke insert privileges from anyone but the stored procedure .   Side note : your 4 selects can be replaced with just one.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot the last END; just typo, but otherwise:

Error: PLS-00405: subquery not allowed in this context
when you call the IF with IN operator.

you have to change your if, like this:

```
 select count(1) into l_count From A where color='red' and Name = :new.name;

 if (l_count>0) THEN ....
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('There are '....
 end if;
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed, but still think about how to solve it, maybe separate it into 2 triggers.